# Find the solution to this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The equation is the following

$2^x-x^2-100=0$

It was handed to me today by a friend student of mine.
I hope you enjoy it .

Comment: straight forward numerical solution is $\approx 7.2537741220288827684385079274892242187$, I don't see where the joy is.

Comment: We enjoy a lot of math, but...do we have to solve this for us or for you? What is your question here?

Comment: Differential equations?

Answer (score 1):

Use the old workhorse, Newton's Iteration:

$ x = 5.0 $

$ \text{2) } x=x-\frac{2^x-x^2-100}{2^x \log (2)-2 x} $

Repeat step 2).

x = 7.253774122028883

Answer (score 0):

if we put $y=2^x$

then $x=log_2(y)$

so we  so we have

$y-(log_2(y))^2-100=0$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y-%28log_2%28y%29%29%5E2-100%3D0

we have this solution,now $y=152.617$

and  $x=log_2(y)=7.253771863$